# How to add columns and rows in reactjs hooks

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks

I need to add column and row dynamically in an array on button click, with react hooks, could someone guide me how to do this?

I have only found information of adding rows dynamically, not both.

Comment: Could you post your attempt ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-leftpad-lclnxw?file=/src/App.js